# Search vim help for subject under cursor

Tags: vim, neovim

While working with some Vim scripts, I found myself typing

```
:help {subject}
```

quite a bit. I want <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (jump to definition of keyword under cursor) functionality, but instead of running `:tag {ident}` I want it to do `:help {subject}`, where `{subject}` is the word under the cursor.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just press `K`. If you have set a global `'keywordprg'`, you need to unset it (or set it to the special `:help` value) in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/vim.vim`:

```
:setlocal keywordprg=:help
```

Comment: This works like a champ and still keeps K for man page lookups working elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: @DougRichardson and IngoKarkat I haven't been able to put this in modeline for my `.vimrc`. Should I take the `aucmd` approach? Otherwise, I might just use `<leader>K` with ZyX's solution.

Comment: I don't know if modelines work with this method. I just tried using `" vim: keywordprg=:help` and got a message `E520: Not allowed in a modeline: keywordprg=`.

Comment: I now have `au FileType vim setl keywordprg=:help`. Oh... that must be what the `ftplugin/vim.vim` is for. Oops.

Comment: Either one is fine. I prefer the au method myself. Then it's in my .vimrc, which is in the cloud.

Comment: To do it with a modeline @DougRichardson, set it in your buffer first. Then in command mode (:), type something like... let mode_line = printf( "Keywordprg: %s", &keywordprg )... hit enter

Comment: ... (sorry) then :call append(line("."), ml)... hit enter.   This will paste that setting on the current line. To be a true modeline, it needs a little more. Have a look here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic

Comment: If you just need the window as a reference (or at least most time), you can save yourself a couple of strokes adding `au FileType vim nnoremap <buffer> K K<c-w><c-p>`.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest solution is

```
nnoremap K :help <C-r><C-w><CR>
```

Comment: Well, almost. Looks like that hi-jacks man page lookups. Is there anyway to get both?

Comment: Yes... map <F1> to the above, and leave <K> alone. Then you get both. If you really want them on the same key, then use an autogroup and autocommands to change the mapping based on filetype. If anyone needs to see that, just ask and I will post something.

Comment: @xizdaqrian One does not need to bother with autocommands and changing mapping: just define `<expr>` mapping which depending on some condition will either use built-in `K` or `:h`: `nnoremap <expr> K (&filetype is# 'vim' ? (':help ' . fnameescape(expand('<cword>')) . "\n") : 'K')`.

Answer (score -3):

To check the documentation of the keyword under your cursor, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to go to its documentation.

If you have enable mouse support in nvim with the following options:

```
set mouse=a
```

you can double click the keyword to go to its documentation.

By the way, to go back to previous position in the help file, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

The above is also true for Neovim.

### References

- https://vimhelp.org/